# How return a list in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to return a list of char in a function PL/SQL with Oracle 11, but without succes.
I've got a few difficulties for understand their running...

For example, i have this code created for test:

```
    create type test is table of varchar(500);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2 (id INT)
RETURN test
is
tt_t test;
BEGIN

SELECT descriptifSpecifique INTO tt_t(1)
FROM DECOMPOSE
where idRecette=id
AND idEtape=2;


SELECT descriptifSpecifique INTO tt_t(2)
FROM DECOMPOSE
where idRecette=id
AND idEtape=3;
RETURN tt_t;
END;
/


show errors function test;
```

The fonction is created without compilation's problem, but at the execution, I have this message: ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection.

Also, how can I return a type (with a varchar and a int generated by a select for example) IN PL/SQL. Because when I try to make a declaration of type with RECORD, and RETURN this type, I have compilation's problem because type is not declarated...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically doing it correctly.  But you need to `EXTEND` your collection before you put new elements into it.

Personally, I prefer to `BULK COLLECT` into the collection to avoid having to `EXTEND` and manage the entries at each index.  Like this (code untested):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2 (id INT)
RETURN test
is
tt_t test;
BEGIN

SELECT descriptifSpecifique
BULK COLLECT INTO tt_t
FROM DECOMPOSE
where idRecette=id
AND idEtape IN (2,3)
ORDER BY idEtape;

RETURN tt_t;
END;
/
```

To return a `TYPE` having multiple columns, you need to create two types: an `OBJECT` type and a `TABLE OF` that object type.

Like so,

```
CREATE TYPE test_rec IS OBJECT ( a_varchar VARCHAR2(500), a_number NUMBER);

CREATE TYPE test_tbl IS TABLE OF test_rec;
```

Then, you can modify your function accordingly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2 (id INT)
RETURN test_tbl
is
tt_t test_tbl;
BEGIN

SELECT test_rec(idEtape, descriptifSpecifique)
BULK COLLECT INTO tt_t
FROM DECOMPOSE
where idRecette=id
AND idEtape IN (2,3)
ORDER BY idEtape;

RETURN tt_t;
END;
/
```

Comment: it works perfectly thank u a lot. have u an idea for my other question?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see second part.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank u. They are a difference between OBJECT and RECORD ?

Comment: `RECORD` is PL/SQL only.  In Oracle 12c, you can use a `RECORD` type, but it must be defined in a package spec I believe.